# Setting a Type's Property values from dynamic UI controls

Tags: c#, winforms, reflection, user-interface, controls

I have a Business layer with a namespace in it called Products. so: Business.Products

Using Reflection, I load all types (except base classes, not Abstract ones) into a combobox and expect the user to select a type (Book, Food, Medicine, Other :all inherits from ProductBase class) and set its properties and add into a global Order object that contains a List of ProductBase.

So far, I select the type from dropdown, and a groupbox underneath gets filled with corresponding UI controls, CheckBox for a bool prop, DateTimePicker for a datetime one, TextBox for free-entry and so on. (I place the propertyinfo instance on the Tag property of the control btw)

When it comes to adding the new property after UI ctrls are set, I instanciate a new instace of the selected type and start setting its properties. To find the corr UI ctrl I loop through the Controls in the groupBox and use the Tag prop that carries the PropertyInfo instance. No problem so far finding the associated control. But controls are different types (I return the controls from a private method that returns System.WinForms.Control) and I need to access its SelectedDate property if its a DatePicker, IsChecked prop if its a CheckBox and so on. I don't know what to do right now, frankly speaking :) please help a brother out here, thanks yo'll in advance. Peace!

Note: I see that most of the controls have a Text value, even if its a DatePicker text value looks like a date, but don't think I can really use that.

PS: This is actually a known interview question but I want this Reflection approach in order to support all kinds of future messings with the inheritance structure and moving/adding/removing of properties. 
check here for the question itself: http://codecrafter.blogspot.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you used the PropertyGrid control? It has this sort of thing already baked in. Also, it is the typical Windows Environment way of doing things like this. It also interacts with the System.ComponentModel namespace quite nicely so you can do things like edit the way each property is labeled, description, allowed values ...

Also, be aware, reflection is somewhat slow, so I wouldn't do this on a large scale.